# How to simulate user input?

Tags: clojure

I know that one can simulate a user's input by wrapping the `(read-line)` function in `with-in-str` and then passing your input programmatically like this:

```
(with-in-str "punit naik" (println (read-line)))
```

This will of course print `punit naik` to the console.
But the problem is, I have a function which runs recursively and continuously asks for user input in it's iterations.
And I want to write a test case for that function. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read-line` reads one line at a time. You can prepare a string that contains all of the lines that need to be read separated with new line:

```
(with-in-str
  "a\nb\nc"
  (loop []
    (if-let [line (read-line)]
      (do
        (println "Line was" line)
        (println "Recurring")
        (recur))
      (println "No more lines"))))
```

This prints:

```
Line was a
Recurring
Line was b
Recurring
Line was c
Recurring
No more lines
```